# Safe to erase from map inside range based for?

Tags: c++, dictionary, foreach, range

I often use this syntax to loop through a `std::map`:

```
for( const auto& my_pair: my_map )
```

Can I call `my_map.erase( my_pair.first );` safely?

Comment: [*References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated. Other references and iterators are not affected.*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is *not* safe.

```
my_map.erase( my_pair.first );
```

Here you're calling `erase` with a key value, meaning that you will remove all elements with that key value.

When erasing elements from a `std::map` this applies:

> *References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated. Other references and iterators are not affected.**

<sub>* http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase</sub>

Therefore, it is unsafe to increment the current iterator as it may have been invalidated.

Comment: Thank you!  A range based for is an iterator?

Comment: @Cincinnatus The range-based for loop uses an internal iterator that gets incremented in each iteration. See here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for